# "Optional feature not implemented" error when trying select records using Oracle ODBC driver and Node.js

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, odbc

I tried run query on `Oracle Express 11g r2` database:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE LOWER(table_column) = LOWER('Some random COLUMN VALUE')
```

And in response I received:

```
{ 
  error: '[node-odbc] SQL_ERROR', 
  native: 3,
  message: '[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]Optional feature not implemented.',
  state: 'HYC00',
  type: { 
    code: 1,
    message: 'An error occurred in the Data Access Layer.',
    httpStatus: 500
  },
  toString: [Function] }
```

I tried to find solution. Google mostly says that's ODBC fault. Unfortunately I have to use this driver, so do you know how to fix it ?
For your information, when I run exact this same query in DBeaver (JDBC Driver), everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of Oracle ODBC drivers. One provided by Microsoft (very old one) which is part of default Windows installation. The other is provided by Oracle - being part of Oracle client libs.

I guess you use the Microsoft's one. And you are trying to fetch CLOB - or some other datatype, which is not supported by the driver.

Check columns in the table `table_name` and try to cast them into `VARCHAR2` before fetching (in your query)